# Is a "gas burner" something like a "stove"? room=space?

Tags: meaning, literature

Is a "gas burner"  something like a "stove"? room=space?

> She took up her station against the drawing-room wall, with her arms
>   extended as if she were crucified. Then three **gas-burners** were turned on
>   to their full extent in a room about sixteen feet square. The effect upon
>   Katie King was marvellous.

Comment: They might have been lamps. In ACD's day much domestic lighting was by gas. The location is a drawing-room (lounge) so it is unlikely to mean the burners on a cooking stove. The room, is the drawing-room of that size.

Comment: Please provide the source of this quotation.  If you can link to an online version that would be great, thanks.

Comment: It's domestic gas lighting, not in use these days except as a novelty......https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_lighting#Types_of_lighting_instruments

Comment: @JamesK - it's the same old Conan Doyle book about spiritualism we have become so used to over the last weeks and months.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Given that in the very next sentence we find ***she began gradually to melt away***, I think we can reasonably suppose the primary purpose/effect of those gas-burners was in fact the obvious one - to provide ***heat***, rather than ***light***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica on the contrary, she was an **apparition** which melted away in the *ephemeral* sense, which ACD (or maybe Crookes) describes as **dematerialisation**. There follows a comparison with a wax doll *actually* melting before a hot fire. It was light that destroyed the effect/hoax.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Oh, okay. But that simply confirms my belief that ACD's tracts on Spiritualism aren't particularly suitable material for learning either "natural philosophy" / science *or* English!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I quite agree, and the 19th century writing style isn't really suitable for English learners either IMO.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes, that's my main point. I know it must be irritating to the OP here that I have no time for the *subject matter*, but it's really the *writing style* that makes it unsuitable. It's not even that his style is truly "Victorian" (I think most of his literary output was after Queen Victoria died) - it's almost *deliberately* convoluted / antiquated, for the sake of effect. (An effect mostly lost on me, I'm afraid! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica OT sorry but it was only when I knew of ACD's interest that I realised it could be the source of an aspect of his Holmes character. Mediums are experts in "cold reading" (which is what makes them seem marvellous to the gullible) and that is exactly what Holmes does: deduces a large amount of possibly true information from whatever clues are available.

Comment: @WeatherVane: As it happens, I've been watching some of the early (Basil Rathbone) Sherlock Holmes movies over the last few days. Thus far I've avoided *The Hound of the Baskervilles* because I have a vague recollection from reading the stories in my youth that it's going to irritate me with allusions to the supernatural. But there's nothing like that in the 3 movies I've just watched. Quite the opposite, really, because whenever anyone suggests Holmes might have "supernatural" powers of deduction, he *immediately* sets them straight by rattling off all the "elementary" clues he's picking up!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I wasn't claiming that either Holmes or mediums have supernatural powers. Cold reading is a *skill* that can be highly developed and in both cases they use it to make educated guesses. That's where my analogy stops; I just thought it possible that was an inspiration for Holmes.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes, I think I've understood you perfectly. My point was I'm *relieved* that at least the movies I've recently watched haven't require me to "suspend my **disbelief**" in the supernatural. I can do that if I have to (I have no problem with "totally unbelievable" sci-fi movies, for example). But I don't like to risk being unwittingly encouraged to *continue* to believe in impossible things *after the movie or book finishes*. Specifically, I wouldn't want to be "brainwashed" by ACD.

Comment: Even if regular users are aware what the source is, in one week's time, in one month's time and by Winter anyone looking at this post (without reading all wordy comments) will be utterly clueless as to its origin. P.S Questions always start with a capital letter.

Answer (score -2):

Gas burners - still widely found in many parts of the world - are portable heaters that work off bottles of gas. The bottles are placed inside the device and, when the gas is lighted, the flame heats a grid at the front. They generally have several settings to control the amount of heat given off.

Because these heaters consume oxygen and have led to the deaths of many people in small, unventilated rooms, they have been widely prohibited. Newer models come with chimney stacks that have to be vented outside of the building. In this way they draw in oxygen to replace that being consumed.

Comment: The gas burners in question are used for lighting, given they are located in the drawing room. I took the trouble to Google the text and it's taken from the works of Arthur Conan Doyle and the ´preceding paragraph refers to lighting.